# Select list of element having a child element without a specific class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="A B">
    <span class="C">needed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="A B">
    <span class="D">not needed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="A B">
    <span class="E">needed</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need all the div elements those do not have a child span with class "D". Is there a jQuery selector for this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use combination of **[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** and **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** pseudo-class selectors. Where **[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** can be used for checking the selected element contains any certain element and then filter out them using **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** selector. Although **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method can be use as in ***@Jai*** answer.

```js
$('.A.B:not(:has(>.D))').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="A B">
    <span class="C">needed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="A B">
    <span class="D">not needed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="A B">
    <span class="E">needed</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**FYI :** Where [`>`(children selector)](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) is using to check the direct child otherwise it may check for nested, so you can avoid if it's not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.filter()`:

```js
var divs = $('.A.B').filter(function(){
   return $(this).children('span.D').length === 0;
});

console.log(divs.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="A B">
    <span class="C">needed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="A B">
    <span class="D">not needed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="A B">
    <span class="E">needed</span>
  </div>
</div>
```